# Manipulate a CSS-Variable by clicking

Tags: javascript, css, css-variables

I want to double the value of an elements' property each time it gets clicked. Thereby I am using CSS-variables.
So I am trying to do that:

```
#circle_1 {
width:50px;
height:50px;
width: var(--size_1, 50px);
height: var(--size_1, 50px);
}
```

and that:

```
// Vars
var circle_1 = document.querySelector("#circle_1");
var size_1 = document.getPropertyValue("--size_1");

// Function to grow the circle
function growCircle() {
var size_1_n =size_1*2;
  circle_1.style.setProperty("--size_1", size_1_n.value);
}

// Event listener
var el = document.getElementById("circle_1");
el.addEventListener("click", growCircle, false);
```

You may see it here https://codepen.io/daiaiai/pen/QQXrGz

Nothing is happening. I assume it's something wrong with (at least) var size_1 = document.getPropertyValue("--size_1");
but I can't really figure it out. Could you guide me a bit (much) please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a lot of problems with your codepen, so I will clean up your code, and present a working example instead.

Here are some key changes:

1. I have added a `:root` delcaration for the variable. This allows me to get the value of `--size_1` at the element `circle_1`. Without this, you'd get `NaN` as the value of the variable, as it is not declared anywhere in the styles.

   You *could* write some conditions to get the computed `width` or `height` values, but I felt it is cleaner to put a default value in `:root`.
2. Since you are setting the value like `50px` instead of `50`, i.e. value with units, you need to get the numerical part out of it before you could double it. I am using `parseInt(size_1)` for that.

```js
var circle_1 = document.querySelector("#circle_1");
var size_1 = document.body.style.getPropertyValue("--size_1");

// Function to grow the circle
function growCircle() {
  var size_1 = window.getComputedStyle(circle_1).getPropertyValue("--size_1");
  var size_1_n = parseInt(size_1) * 2;
  circle_1.style.setProperty("--size_1", size_1_n + "px");
}


// Event listener
circle_1.addEventListener("click", growCircle, false);
```

```css
:root {
  --size_1: 50px;
}

body {
  margin: 100px;
}

#circle_1 {
  width: var(--size_1, 50px);
  height: var(--size_1, 50px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
  opacity: 0.7;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

div span {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle_1" draggable="true"><span>Group 1<span></div>
```

---

A slightly different approach to this would be to declare the value part only in the variable's `:root` declaration. You could then refer to its value using `width: calc(var(--size_1) * 1px)`.

I personally prefer this approach as the variable only carries the value component, and you could apply any unit you like at the time of declaring a style. Also, this would allow you to avoid the `parseInt` of variable's value.

Here's a snippet with that approach:

```js
var circle_1 = document.querySelector("#circle_1");
var size_1 = document.body.style.getPropertyValue("--size_1");

// Function to grow the circle
function growCircle() {
  var size_1 = window.getComputedStyle(circle_1).getPropertyValue("--size_1");
  var size_1_n = size_1 * 2;
  circle_1.style.setProperty("--size_1", size_1_n);
}


// Event listener
circle_1.addEventListener("click", growCircle, false);
```

```css
:root {
  --size_1: 50;
}

body {
  margin: 100px;
}

#circle_1 {
  width: calc(var(--size_1, 50px) * 1px);
  height: calc(var(--size_1, 50px) * 1px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
  opacity: 0.7;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

div span {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle_1" draggable="true"><span>Group 1<span></div>
```